# 'Converting' PLSQL Trigger to StoredProcedure SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

My database has tables Item, Ingredients, ItemContains, BillItem. Item is 'made' of one or more Ingredients, and that is presented in table ItemContains (IDItem - IDIngredient - ContainingQuantity). When I insert record into BillItem, which also has Quantity (BillItemQuantity) field, I want Trigger or StoredProcedure to reduce value of Quantity field in Ingredient table

**(IngredientQuantity = IngredientQuantity - BillItemQuantity*ContainingQuantity)**,

but the problem is when Item contains more than one Ingredient, don't know where to put IDIngredient, I tried with temporary table, but unsuccessfully. I wrote PL/SQL trigger for Oracle Database, and it works, so if someone can help with 'converting' that into SQL Server procedure or something like that, I would highly appreciate that. Thanks.

```
create or replace 
trigger ReduceQuantity
before insert on BillItem
for each row
declare
  quaN BillItem.Quantity%type;
  quaO BillItem.Quantity%type;
  idIt integer;
  idItOld integer;
  type RecCon is record (IngID ItemContains.idIngredient%type, Qua ItemContains.quantity%type);
  type TableQuantity is table of RecCon index by binary_integer;
  i binary_integer:=0;

  TabQuant TableQuantity;

begin
  idIt:= :New.IDItem;
  idItOld:= :Old.IDItem;
  quaN := :New.Quantity;
  kolS := :Old.Quantity;

  for rec in (select IDIngredient, Quantity from ItemContains where IDItem = idIt) loop
    TabQuant(i).IngID := rec.IDIngredient;
    TabKol(i).Qua := rec.Quantity;
    i:=i+1;
  end loop;

  if inserting then 
    i:=TabQuant.first;
    while i<=TabQuant.last loop
            update Ingredient set Quantity=Quantity-TabQuant(i).Qua*quaN where IDIngredient = TabQuant(i).IngID;
           i:=TabKol.Next(i);
    end loop; 

  end if;
end ReduceQuantity;
```

Here is the entire script that you can run in SQL Fiddle. It's shortened, but it's fully functional for this problem. So I want trigger to reduce quantity in Ingredient table on inserting new BillItem (example: 2 Cappuccinos in BillItem will reduces 'Espresso coffee' for 2 pieces and 'Milk' for 0.10 l)

```
create table Item(
    IDItem integer NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ItemType varchar(9),
    Unit varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    Price decimal(5,2),
    CONSTRAINT item_PK PRIMARY KEY (IDItem),
    CONSTRAINT item_UQ UNIQUE (Name),
    CONSTRAINT item_unit_CHK CHECK (Unit in ('g', 'kg', 'ml', 'dl', 'l', 'pc')),
    CONSTRAINT item_type_CHK CHECK (ItemType in ('Food', 'Beverage'))
    );

create table Ingredient(
    IDIngredient integer NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Type varchar(9),
    Unit varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    IngredientQuantity decimal(6,2),
    CONSTRAINT ingredient_PK PRIMARY KEY (IDIngredient),
    CONSTRAINT ingredient_UQ UNIQUE (Name),
    CONSTRAINT ingredient_unit_CHK CHECK (Unit in ('g', 'kg', 'ml', 'dl', 'l', 'pc')),
    CONSTRAINT ingredient_type_CHK CHECK (TipSastojka in ('Food', 'Beverage')),
    CONSTRAINT ingredient_UQ1 CHECK(IngredientQuantity>=0)
);

create table ItemContains(
    IDItem integer NOT NULL,
    IDIngredient integer NOT NULL,
    ContainsQuantity decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ItemContains_PK PRIMARY KEY (IDItem, IDIngredient),
    CONSTRAINT ItemContains_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (IDItem) references Item(IDItem),
    CONSTRAINT ItemContains_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (IDIngredient) references Ingredient(IDIngredient)
    );

create table Bill(
    IDBill integer NOT NULL,
    BillDate varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    TotalPrice decimal(8,2),
    CONSTRAINT bill_PK PRIMARY KEY (IDBill)
    );


create table BillItem(
    IDBillItem integer NOT NULL,
    IDBill integer NOT NULL,
    IDItem integer NOT NULL,
    BillItemQuantity decimal(3,1),
    CONSTRAINT billitem_PK PRIMARY KEY (IDBillItem),
    CONSTRAINT billitem_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (IDItem) references Item(IDItem),
    CONSTRAINT billitem_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (IDBill) references bill(IDBill)
);


Insert into Ingredient values(1, 'Amstel draft', 'Beverage', 'l', 100);
Insert into Ingredient values(2, 'Espresso coffee', 'Beverage', 'pc', 275);
Insert into Ingredient values(3, 'Milk', 'Beverage', 'l', 90);

Insert into Item values(1, 'Amstel - small', 'Beverage', 'l', 5);
Insert into Item values(2, 'Amstel - large', 'Beverage', 'l', 7);
Insert into Item values(3, 'Espresso', 'Beverage', 'pc', 4.5);
Insert into Item values(4, 'Cappuccino', 'Beverage', 'pc', 5.5);

Insert into ItemContains(IDItem, IDIngredient,ContainsQuantity) values(1, 1, 0.3);
Insert into ItemContains(IDItem, IDIngredient,ContainsQuantity) values(2, 1, 0.5);
Insert into ItemContains(IDItem, IDIngredient,ContainsQuantity) values(3, 2, 1);
Insert into ItemContains(IDItem, IDIngredient,ContainsQuantity) values(4, 2, 1);
Insert into ItemContains(IDItem, IDIngredient,ContainsQuantity) values(4, 3, 0.05);

insert into Bill values(1, '12-jun-2013', null);

Insert into BillItem(IDBillItem, IDBill, IDItem, BillItemQuantity) values(1, 1, 1, 3);
Insert into BillItem(IDBillItem, IDBill, IDItem, BillItemQuantity) values(2, 1, 2, 1);
Insert into BillItem(IDBillItem, IDBill, IDItem, BillItemQuantity) values(3, 1, 3, 1);
Insert into BillItem(IDBillItem, IDBill, IDItem, BillItemQuantity) values(4, 1, 4, 2);


CREATE VIEW ItemsIngredientsView  AS 
  select sa.IDItem as "ID Item",  art.Name as "Item name", sa.ContainsQuantity as "Quantity", s.Unit as "Unit", s.IDIngredient as "ID Ingredient", s.Name as "Ingredient name" from ItemContains sa left join Ingredient s on sa.IDIngredient=s.IDIngredient left join Item art on art.IDItem = sa.IDItem;

CREATE VIEW BillView AS 
  select r.IDBill as "Bill", sr.IDItem as "ID Item", art.Name as "Item Name", sr.BillItemQuantity as "Quantity", art.Price as "Price" from Bill r right join BillItem sr on r.IDBill=sr.IDBill left join Item art on sr.IDItem = art.IDItem;

CREATE VIEW BillTotalPriceView AS 
  select sum(sr.BillItemQuantity*art.Price) as "TotalPrice" from Bill r right join BillItem sr on r.IDBill=sr.IDBill left join Item art on sr.IDItem = art.IDItem;
```

Comment: Where does `TabKol` come from (did you mean to call it `TabQuant`? Also, we need more detail. Please provide at least ONE set of sample data for each table. It is NOT clear how the tables join to each other and what their cardinality relationship is. Why would you multiply `BillItemQuantity` by `ContainingQuantity`? It doesn't make sense, yet.

Comment: Yes, that should be TabQuant, I was translating from my language, sorry.

Comment: Most excellent. I will make some time soon to look at this again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still stuck here...

Comment: This kind of detail is *always* the best way to get a good answer. Good job! If you'd made me come up with all that setup script myself, it might have taken a good while longer before I could have answered. There were still a couple of typos but I fixed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough outline of how you handle creating a set-based trigger that SQL Server requires, instead of the row-by-row trigger from Oracle:

1. Use the `inserted` and `deleted` meta-tables to find the change in quantity (the post-update and pre-update values, where `deleted` is empty if it is an insert and `inserted` is empty if it is a delete).
2. Sum the changes per `IngredientID`.
3. Join the derived table containing the sum of needed adjustments to the `Ingredient` table and perform the `UPDATE`.

Using your sample schema (**extremely** helpful, thank you--without it I couldn't have done this), here's what the trigger looks like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BillItem_UpdateQuantity
   ON dbo.BillItem FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE N
SET N.IngredientQuantity = N.IngredientQuantity - Change
FROM
   dbo.Ingredient N
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
         IC.IDIngredient,
         Change =
            Sum(
               (IsNull(I.BillItemQuantity, 0) - IsNull(D.BillItemQuantity, 0))
               * IC.ContainsQuantity
            )
      FROM
         Inserted I
         FULL JOIN Deleted D
            ON I.IDBillItem = D.IDBillItem
         INNER JOIN dbo.ItemContains IC
            ON IsNull(I.IDItem, D.IDItem) = IC.IDItem
      GROUP BY
         IC.IDIngredient
   ) S ON N.IDIngredient = S.IDIngredient
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/412b4/1)

Depending on the DML operation, one of the `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables can be empty, so we `FULL JOIN` them so we get both the before and after values available to us. We join to the `ItemContains` table to get the quantities of each ingredient, and sum the changes, grouping by the ingredient so we can build up a total to modify each one. The `IsNull` parts handle when it is a `DELETE` or an `INSERT` since in those cases there no value being changed to, or no value being changed from, but we still have to adjust properly.

You should think a little about how you will handle cancellations or refunds. Be careful about any data operation, as it WILL update the ingredient on-hand amount.

Comment: I've just added some additional information to my question. I suppose it's more understandable now.

Comment: @Marko Thanks for the reminder. I have updated my answer. I hope this helps you. If you view the edit I made, you will see that the query has not changed form very much... I was just able to flesh out the full details this time.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is more than helpful! After little bit adjusting to my database I've tried it, and it works! I'm only not sure what do you mean by 'cancellations or refunds'?

Comment: Please note: you should probably add the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` line that I just put into the trigger. This prevents having weird additional rowcounts show up when doing DML. These rowcounts can also break ADO commands (think VB6/VBScript/Classic ASP).